# .NET Angular Shopping cart

Tags: c#, .net, angular, cart, shopping-cart

I'm writing a website (.NET 6, Angular 14) (an online electronics store) that has a shopping cart. I don't know how to properly implement a shopping cart. It is necessary to write a service for adding device, deleting device, emptying the cart, the total price of cart. Each user should have their own shopping cart and now I don't know how to do it. If I write a service in Angular, then when I update the site, all the devices in the cart that I put in the cart disappear, and if I write on the .net, it turns out that each user should have their own table with baskets. I think there is a correct way to implement this, but I can't find a solution. Please help me what should I do.

Service written with Angular:

```
  public cartItemList : any =[]
  public deviceList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  public search = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  constructor() { }

  getProducts(){
    return this.deviceList.asObservable();
  }

  setDevice(device : any){
    this.cartItemList.push(...device);
    this.deviceList.next(device);
  }
  addtoCart(device : any){
    this.cartItemList.push(device);
    this.deviceList.next(this.cartItemList);
    this.getTotalPrice();
    console.log(this.cartItemList)
  }
  getTotalPrice() : number{
    let grandTotal = 0;
    this.cartItemList.map((a:any)=>{
      grandTotal += a.total;
    })
    return grandTotal;
  }
  removeCartItem(device: any){
    this.cartItemList.map((a:any, index:any)=>{
      if(device.id=== a.id){
        this.cartItemList.splice(index,1);
      }
    })
    this.deviceList.next(this.cartItemList);
  }
  removeAllCart(){
    this.cartItemList = []
    this.deviceList.next(this.cartItemList);
  }
}
```

Service with API:

```
  public cartItemList : any =[]
  public deviceList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  public search = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  readonly deviceAPIUrl = "https://localhost:7163/api";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(){
    return this.http.get<ICartDevice[]>(this.deviceAPIUrl + '/cart');
  }

  addToCart(data: any){
    return this.http.put(this.deviceAPIUrl + `/cart/addtocart/${data}`, data);
  }

  getTotalPrice(){
    return this.http.get<number>(this.deviceAPIUrl + '/cart/getTotalPrice');
  }
  
  removeCartItem(id: number | string){
    return this.http.delete<IDevice>(this.deviceAPIUrl + `/cart/removeCartItem/${id}`);
  }

  removeAllCart(){
    return this.http.delete<ICartDevice[]>(this.deviceAPIUrl + '/cart/removeAllCart');
  }
}
```

API for this Service:

```
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public CartController( DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CartDevices>>> GetDevices()
        {
            if (_context.CartTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return await _context.CartTable.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpPut("addToCart/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutDeviceInCart(int id)
        {
            var device = _context.Devices.Find(id);

            if (id != device.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var newCartDevice = new CartDevices
            {
                Name = device.Name,
                Price = device.Price,
                Image = device.Image,
                ShortDescription = device.ShortDescription,
                FullDescription = device.FullDescription,
                CategoryId = device.CategoryId,
                RAM_ID = device.RAM_ID,
                MemoryId = device.MemoryId,
                Amount = device.Amount
            };

            _context.CartTable.Add(newCartDevice);
            GetTotalPrice();
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(newCartDevice);
        }

        [HttpGet("getTotalPrice")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTotalPrice()
        {
            var totalPrice = _context.CartTable.ToList().Sum(p => p.Price);

            return Ok(totalPrice);
        }

        [HttpDelete("removeCartItem/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteDevice(int id)
        {
            if (_context.CartTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var device = await _context.CartTable.FindAsync(id);
            if (device == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.CartTable.Remove(device);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("removeAllCart")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAllCart(int id)
        {
            if (_context.CartTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var devices = await _context.CartTable.ToListAsync();

            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                if (device == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                _context.CartTable.Remove(device);
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you read some books about .Net, get the basic of backend, then master basic javascript, get some books to get the gist of angular and frontend, and then get some books combine both Angular and .Net together. You need to walk before you can run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular, you can use localStorage to store the data.
The issue with this approach would be you will lose the data if you login into some other system.

==================================================================

In .NET, you should use a database and store it as a JSON (this way you can avoid multiple rows for each item) and keep track of the status of the cart.